# i want to find the span of a array. Span is defined as difference of maximum value and minimum value

Tags: java, arrays

I tried by creating two functions for greatest and smallest values and then subtracting them .but the code doesn't seem to work
here's the code.See if u could help me out .im new to java and still learning.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

public static void smler(int arr[],int j){
    for (int i=0;i<=j;j++){
        if(arr[i]<arr[i+1]){
        int temp =arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
public static void grter(int arr[],int j){
    for (int i=0;i<=j;j++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
        int temp =arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1]=temp;
    }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
  int n=sc.nextInt();
  int[] arr= new int[n];
  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
      arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
  }
  grter(arr,n);
 int y= arr[n];
 smler(arr,n);
 int z = arr[n];
 System.out.println(y-z);
 }
}
```

Comment: Which specific issue do you have?  `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception is caused by invalid upper limit in all `for` loops.  Indexes of arrays in java start from to `n - 1`, so they look: `for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++)`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Main.main(Main.java:29)
this was the exception shown

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is not reproducible, only `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an approach very similar to what you want to do.

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

public static int smler(int arr[],int N){
    int smaller = arr[0];

    for (int i=1;i<N;i++){
        if(arr[i] < smaller){
          smaller = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return smaller;
}
public static int grter(int arr[],int N){
    int greater = arr[0];

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(arr[i] > greater){
          greater = arr[i];
        }
    }
    
    return greater;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
  int n=sc.nextInt();
  int[] arr= new int[n];
  for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
      arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
  }
  
 System.out.println(grter(arr, n) - smler(arr, n));
 }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)` ,it should be `i<n`

Comment: thank you for this code it really helped to understand something basic and cleared my doubts and will use the same.

Comment: This code has the same bug as OP's `for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)`; `N` does not need to be passed to the methods, arrays have `length` property

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This code is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of errors in your logic.

The for loop does not need to be `<=` it needs to be `<` otherwise you will get out of bounds exception.

The way you are calculating the min and max are wrong.

Here is an example for you to study that does what you are trying to accomplish:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySpan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter array size:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter value:");
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int min = findMin(arr);
        int max = findMax(arr);

        System.out.println("The span of the array = " + (max - min));
        sc.close();
    }

    static int findMax(int[] a) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] > max)
                max = a[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    static int findMin(int[] a) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] < min)
                min = a[i];
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

and output:

```
Enter array size:
3
Enter value:
1
Enter value:
2
Enter value:
3
The span of the array = 2
```

Comment: thank you for this code it really helped to understand something basic and cleared my doubts and will use the same.

Comment: @alex-rudenko True! Ability to post does not mean ability to absorb the approach.

Comment: ik the this approch was better but the answer that i was searching for or the code that was similar to my logic was the other one mb i might be wrong but im new  so dont mind. :)

Comment: @KumarAshutosh well thats true I might not truly get all as I'm still learning but I'm still trying my best to absorb all.

Comment: @SanskarTyagi When you are on StackOverflow do not accept incorrect answers otherwise people in your position will follow an incorrect approach. It also reflects poorly on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

It would better if you could look for complexity improvement.

Idea is to get the max and the min in best possible way and this can be achieved using any sorting techniques, let us assume your sort method runs in `O(n log n)` time, and then you just need to get the difference of 1st element(`0 th index`) and last element(`n-1 th index`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
  int n=sc.nextInt();

  int[] arr= new int[n];

  // insert values into your array

  if(arr.length >= 2){
    sort(arr); // Implement your any sorting method

    // Make sure that your arr has exactly n elements, ,
    // Otherwise rest of the indices will all be zero(0)
    System.out.println(arr[0]-arr[arr.length-1]); // last index is 'arr.length-1'
    return; // Return from here
  }

  // arr has not sufficient elements to determine span
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Invalid entry");
  
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. it helped me to understand the different approach through my method.

Comment: With this code you plan on running insertion sort *after* you have inserted all the values into the array? How is the time complexity O(log n)? This makes no sense.

Comment: I got you, but it never said if that's online or not. If he knew there is something called sorting, he might have chosen accordingly! Apologies, but I just voted for sorting part.

Answer (score 0):

1. Index starts from 0 and it goes till n-1. 
   So, the condition in for-loop should be `i<n` instead of `i<=n`,`for(int i=0;i<n;i++)`.
2. You have created 2 functions but it doesn't return any value nor changes anything. As you are passing the array by value, not by references.
3. You don't need the 2 functions, just one for finding max and min in linear, or sort the array in ascending order and `array[0]` will be the min and `array[n-1]` will be max.

Comment: i created two functions so as to learn the flow of functions while using arrays 
i could have done it with eaiser way but i wanted to learn using functions in array